# Getting nested values in Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

According to the docs here: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/getIn

I should be able to get the deeply nested value by providing an array for the `keyPath` argument. This is what I've done, however I'm getting `undefined` as the return value.

http://jsfiddle.net/srxv4mwu/

```
var obj = Immutable.Map({categories: {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}});
var output = obj.getIn(['categories', 1]);
alert(output);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you for this question, why have the docs seemingly disappeared for `getIn` ? Has the method been deprecated?

Comment: Sorry, apparently it's inherited: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Iterable/getIn

Answer (score 57, accepted):

A map is simply a collection of keys with values. What you have is a map with the key `categories`, and the value `{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}`. The value does not automatically become an Immutable map just because you place it inside another map.

Now, the `getIn()` function will only "see" other Immutable.js maps. What you have in there is a regular ol' javascript object. If you just want to get the `1` value, you can just do:

```js
var obj = Immutable.Map({categories: {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}});
var output = obj.getIn(["categories"])[1];
alert(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

If you want the `categories` collection to also be a map, you'll have to define that explicitly. Also, as Amit pointed out, you'll need to use strings with the `getIn()` function.

```js
var obj = Immutable.Map({
 categories: Immutable.Map({
  1: 'a',
  2: 'b'
 })
});
var output = obj.getIn(['categories', '1']);
alert(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

The above code will return `'a'`.

It would probably be more convenient for you to do something like below, if you have many nested maps.

```js
var obj = Immutable.fromJS({
 categories: {
  1: 'a',
  2: 'b'
 }
});
var output = obj.getIn(['categories', '1']);
alert(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

The `fromJs()` function will convert any nested objects into maps or lists automatically for you.

Comment: Now the snippets work. The Immutable libraries weren't linked before.

Comment: "Now, the getIn() function will only "see" other Immutable.js maps. What you have in there is a regular ol' javascript object...."

I posted a question related to this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025635/deep-access-in-plain-objects-with-immutable

The documentation quoted there seems to indicate that plain objects are also supported with getIn ?

Answer (score 18):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. `Immutable.Map(...)` doesn't traverse the parameter to create a complex immutable. For that you need `Immutable.fromJS(...)`.
2. Once you do that, you need to use strings in `getIn(...)`, so `['categories', '1']` instead of `['categories', 1]`.

See [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srxv4mwu/1/).