# Immutable.js accesing value inside Angular's *ngFor

Tags: angular, immutable.js

I have a simple test Immutable.js Map:

```
this.numberMap = Immutable.Map({
                first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, big: 100000
            });
```

Now I try to iterate over this Map with Angular's *ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let n of numberMap">
    {{n}}
</div>
```

It appears that n is referencing whole entry (key + value), and prints key separated by coma then value. I am unable to access this value, I was unable to find a way to access key or value part of n in any way, is there any way to access these separately?

I tried to iterate with for each over this map to find the value/key properties but forEach unfortunately iterates only through value.

Comment: I am not sure , if this helps or not but can you please have a look in this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33910529/1249386

Comment: " I was unable to find a way to access key or value part of n " have you tried `n[0]` for key and `n[1]` for value?

Comment: Amazing, thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments I learned that this pair is returned as normal Array with two entries, so you can access key as n[0] and value as n[1].